# how to manage ssh keys when working with github

Tags: git

I am working with two different private repositories from github and I have generated two pair keys for each of them and I have a config file as below:

```
Host github.com-frontend
HostName github.com
User lulzimfazlija2
IdentitiesOnly yes
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_frontend

Host github.com-backend
HostName github.com
User lulzimfazlija2
IdentitiesOnly yes
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_backend
```

The thing is when I try to push from any of the project it still asks me to write the passphrase from the id_rsa and not id_rsa_frontend or id_rsa_backend.

How can I tell to git to always identify from one single key.

I am also trying this:

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com-frontend
```

Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/lulzim/.ssh/id_rsa_frontend':
Hi lulzimfazlija2/venture-frontend! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

but, when I do git push it still asks me to write passkey from the id_rsa key.

Is there any way that I can set git it to always asks me from specific key for each project.

Comment: What is the URL you're attempting to git push to? give us the output of `git remote -v`

Comment: Also, what is the problem? That you need to type your password each time?

Comment: its: git@github.com:lulzimfazlija2/venture-backend.git

Comment: no, the problem is, it asks me to write the passphrase for id_rsa not id_rsa_frontend for example when i try to push or pull

Comment: You're pushing to github.com, not github.com-frontend or github.com-backend. You'll have to either change the remote url with `git remote set-url` or add github.com to your ssh config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ssh -T git@github.com-frontend` is valid and will push to github.com according to your `~/.ssh/config`.

However:

- Make sure in your `~/.ssh/config` to include `User git`, not `User lulzimfazlija2`: you always push to GitHub (in ssh) as `git`, not as `xxx`: GitHub will authenticate you with the public ssh key ([that is associated to your GitHub account](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/)).
  Your valid test (`ssh -T git@github.com-frontend`) actually includes the user `git` (which is correct).
  If `User git` is included in `~/.ssh/config`, your test would actually be:
  `ssh -T github.com-frontend`
- Enter passphrase for key means your private ssh key is passphrase-protected.
  If you want to avoid entering said passphrase every time you are using it, you need to [add that ssh key to your ssh agent](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent).
  In a git bash:

  ```
  eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_frontend
  ```

Then you can use origin url such as:

```
github.com-frontend:lulzimfazlija2/my_frontend_project
github.com-backend:lulzimfazlija2/my_backend_project
```

(no need for a '`git@`' prefix, as `User git` would be declared in the `~/.ssh/config`)